# Snapshot unit test fail for react-native-modal-datetime-picker

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme, snapshot

In my component I use DateTimePicker from react-native-modal-datetime-picker. DateTimePicker has a props date that is intialise with new Date(). When I tried to do unit test the snapshot is created but fails every time because the date prop.

```
it('should renders successfully', () => {
    mockDate('2019-09-17');
    const props = {
      maxStartDate: mockDate('2019-09-17'),
      setMinEndDate: jest.fn(),
    }; - this is my props
    const tree = shallow(<StartDate {...props} />);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

I mocked the date like that but for date prop from DateTimePicker doesn't work.

```
const RealDate = Date;
const mockDate = (isoDate) => {
  global.Date = class extends RealDate {
    constructor(...args) {
      if (args.length) {
        return new RealDate(...args);
      }
      return new RealDate(isoDate);
    }
  };
};
```